# Testing WCF methods with Nunit but WebOperationContext is null

Tags: wcf, nunit, weboperationcontext

How do you get around the WebOperationContext being null in a WCF service method when testing the method using NUnit

I have a unit test project using NUnit to test data returned by a WCF Method:

```
public class SampleService
{
   public XmlDocument Init ()
   {
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
      return _defaultInitializationXMLfile;
   }
}
```

Then I have a Test Method as follows

```
[TextFixture]
public class SampleServiceUnitTest
{
   [Test]
   public void DefaultInitializationUnitTest
   {
      SampleService sampleService = new SampleService();
      XMLDocument xmlDoc = sampleService.Init();
      XMLNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("defaultNode");
      Assert.IsNotNull(xmlNode, "the default XML element does not exist.");
   }
 }
```

However I'm getting an error during the test stating

```
 SampleServiceUnitTest.DefaultInitializationUnitTest:
 System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

regarding the WebOperationContext in the SampleService Method.

Answer (score 5):

Typically you would want to mock the `WebOperationContext` in some way. There is some stuff built into [WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/) that can do this for you.

Alternatively, you can use some dependency injection to get the WebOperationContext from somewhere else, breaking that dependency, like:

```
public class SampleService
{
   private IWebContextResolver _webContext;

   // constructor gets its dependency, a web context resolver, passed to it.
   public SampleService(IWebContextResolver webContext)
   {
      _webContext = webContext;
   }

   public XmlDocument Init ()
   {
      _webContext.GetCurrent().OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
      return _defaultInitializationXMLfile;
   }
}

public class MockWebContextResolver : IWebContextResolver
{
    public WebOperationContext GetCurrent()
    {
        return new WebOperationContext(...); // make and return some context here
    }
}

public class ProductionWebContextResolver : IWebContextResolver
{
    public WebOperationContext GetCurrent()
    {
        return WebOperationContext.Current;
    }
}
```

There are of course other ways to set up a dependency injection scheme, I just used passing it into the service constructor in this case as an example.